# How used sweetalert with tag<a> in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I will create a sweet alert inside tag(a) in HTML Until the user Clicked the button **Delete** First show 
sweet alert  and if the user clicked the Ok then delete
because click the button delete first delete the article then show me sweet alert

tag::

```
 <a  href="<?php $this->url('article/destroy/'.$article['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

this is sweet alert::

```
 <script>
                    function showmeg(){
                        swal({
                            title: "Are you sure?",
                            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                            icon: "warning",
                            buttons: true,
                            dangerMode: true,
                        })
                            .then((willDelete) => {
                                if (willDelete) {
                                    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {

                                        icon: "success",
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
                                }
                            });
                    }

                </script>
```

>

Answer (score 0):

To show **SweetAlert** before deleting a record, you can use **Ajax** request.

When you click on tag(a) at that time you can call function **deleteRecord()** and pass record id which you want to delete.

For detail, you can refer below example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SweetAlert</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(123)">Delete</a>
  <script>
    function deleteRecord(id) {
      swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
            // Ajax call to delete record  
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://jsonmonk.com/api/v1/users/5e11c1b07e6e9c060654ebf4', // Dummy API (use your delete request here)
              success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 200) {
                  swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                  });
                } else {
                  // Show error alert if unable to delete 
                  swal("Error!", "Something went wrong!", "error");
                }
              }
            });
          } else {
            swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
          }
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```